# How to find a phrase in a large text file in Python?

Tags: python, file

I am trying to write an algorithm to find a phrase with words on different lines in a big text file using Python.

The file contents are as follows

```
fkerghiohgeoihhgergerig ooetbjoptj
enbotobjeob hi how
are you lerjgoegjepogjejgpgrg]
ekrngeigoieghetghehtigehtgiethg
ieogetigheihietipgietigeitgegitie
.......
```

The algorithm should search for the phrase "hi how are you" and return True in this case.
Since, the file can be huge, all file contents cannot be read at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file one character at a time and change line feeds to spaces. Then its just a question of running down the list of wanted characters.

```
def find_words(text, fileobj):
    i = 0
    while True:
        c = fileobj.read(1)
        if not c:
           break
        if c == "\n": # python combines \r\n
            c = " "
        if c != text[i]:
            i = 0
        if c == text[i]:
            i += 1
            if i == len(text):
               return True
    return False
```

If you want to be a little more liberal about whitespace and case sensitivity, you could remove all whitespace and lower case everything before the compare.

```
import re
import itertools
from string import whitespace

def find_words(text, fileobj):
    chars = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(re.split(r"\s+", text.lower())))
    i = 0
    while True:
        c = fileobj.read(1)
        if not c:
            break
        c = c.lower()
        if c in whitespace:
            continue
        if c != chars[i]:
            i = 0
        if c == chars[i]:
            i += 1
            if i == len(chars):
               return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

*Here is one way to solve the problem:*

```
import re

def find_phrase():
    phrase = "hi how are you"
    words = dict(zip(phrase.split(), [False]*len(phrase.split())))
    with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in words:
                if re.search( r"\b" + word + r"\b", line):
                    words[word] = True

                if all(words.values()):
                    return True
    return False
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
def find_phrase():
    phrase = "hi how are you"
    with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if phrase in line:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: The above algorithm does not check for consecutive words, instead checks for a word in a line resulting in false positives

Comment: @RanjanP It does checks.

Comment: @RanjanP Have you tried executing the code? Because I've executed the code and i'm not getting any false positives.

Comment: It fails for the following file `fkerghiohgeoihhgergerig ooetbjoptj
enbotobjeob hi how
are lerj you goegjepogjejgpgrg]
ekrngeigoieghetghehtigehtgiethg
ieogetigheihietipgietigeitgegitie`

Comment: For the above mentioned file, the output should be False

Comment: And why is that so? Could you to explain.

Comment: A phrase is basically a combination of words placed next to each other which means that  all words in a phrase must be continuous. If they are not continuous, then the result must be False

Comment: @RanjanP You have mentioned in your question **I am trying to write an algorithm to find a phrase with words on different lines in a big text file using Python.**. You should have properly posted the question.

Comment: a phrase implicitly means consecutive words

Comment: This is a good answer. But the updated one will not work in the following case, as stated by the user " The string may be to find "hi how are you" and the words of the string are at consecutive lines. The above algorithm may fail for such cases". I have given +1 since it still may be useful for others.  My answer should solve the poblem

Answer (score 0):

If it is "pretty large" file, then access the lines sequentially and don't read the whole file into memory:

```
with open('largeFile', 'r') as inF:
    for line in inF:
        if 'myString' in line:
            # do_something
            break
```

**Edit:**

Since the words of the string can be on consecutive lines you would want to use a counter to keep a track of words iterated. For example,

```
counter = 0
words_list = ["hi","hello","how"]
with open('largeFile', 'r') as inF:
    for line in inF:
        # print( words_list[counter] ,line)
        if words_list[counter] in line and len(line.split()) == 1 :
            counter +=1
        else:
            counter = 0
        if counter == len(words_list):
            print ("here")
            break;
```

Text File

```
fkerghiohgeoihhgergerig ooetbjoptj enbotobjeob
hi
hello
how
goegjepogjejgpgrg] ekrngeigoieghetghehtigehtgiethg ieoge
```

It gives the output `here` since the consecutive words are found

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The string may be to find "hi how are you" and the words of the string are at consecutive lines. The above algorithm may fail for such cases.

Comment: See my update. This method should work efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question with the edited answer. Does it ensure that the words are continuous one after the other? Checking the word in the line may cause false results in this case

Comment: Good find. I have edited the answer. It will now check the string of words continuously since the counter variable is incremented; this is simply used as the index in the list

Comment: The above algorithm still results in false positive as it checks in a complete line and doesn't ensure that words in a phrase are continuous in order

Comment: Is this the string you are exeuting `fkerghiohgeoihhgergerig ooetbjoptj enbotobjeob hi how are lerj you goegjepogjejgpgrg] ekrngeigoieghetghehtigehtgiethg ieogetigheihietipgietigeitgegitie`? Are these on a consecutive lines?

Comment: Yes, they are on consecutive lines

Comment: See my update i have found the problem. Let me know if you still have any problems